# Unable to search for a string in an Array

Tags: ruby

The program reads in a file of tracks and produces a Track array (`tracks`). When the user searches for a specific track (`search_string`) the program returns that it cannot be found, despite there being a track with that name in the array.

```
class Track
    attr_accessor :name, :location
    def initialize (name, location)
        @name = name
        @location = location
    end
end

# search for track by name.
# Returns the index of the track or -1 if not found
def search_for_track_name(tracks, search_string)
    search_string = gets.chomp
    index = 0
while (index < tracks.length)
    tracks.include?(search_string)
    index = index + 1
end
    if tracks.include?(search_string)
        return index
    else
        index = -1
    end
    return index
end
```

Comment: This is vastly over-engineered for Ruby. Are you more used to writing C?

Comment: It's what we've been assigned to do, and this is the way we have to do it

Comment: Need to know what `read_string` does - it looks like a bug that you're passing `search_string` as an argument to `search_for_track_name` but redefine it with a `gets.chomp` in there. Also, your method can be simplified to `tracks.index { |track| track.include?(search_string) } || -1`

Comment: I highly recommend learning to use a debugger like pry by the way, it will allow you to inspect the state at any part of your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to identify if an Array contains a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55920507/unable-to-identify-if-an-array-contains-a-string)

Comment: Why do you duplicate your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition `if tracks.include?(search_string)` will never be `true` because `tracks` is an array of instances of `Track`. And therefore the array doesn't include a specific string.

It might include a track which has a matching name. To find the index of a track that has a matching name [`Array#index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-index) might help:

```
tracks.index { |track| track.name == search_string }
```

Because `index` returns `nil` if the value is not found you can simplify your whole `if...else` block and probably the whole `search_for_track_name` method to just this line:

```
tracks.index { |track| track.name == search_string } || -1
```

Answer (score 1):

I notice your searching loop does nothing. It checks N times if the array includes the search string, *ignores* the result of that check, and adds one to the index. So the index is always going to be N (3 in your case). Then you check *again* whether the array includes the search string, and return -1 if you don't. So your method will always return either N or -1.

Fortunately, Ruby is a language which has already done a lot of the heavy lifting for you. Quite frankly I think you want:

```rb
def search_for_track_name(tracks, search_string)
  tracks.index(search_string) || -1
end
```

`#index` would return `nil` if the search string is not found; this is more standard for Ruby, but since your requirement is to return -1, the `|| -1` will put it in for you. (`nil` and `false` are the *only* falsy values in Ruby, so `||` is a convenient way to shortcut to a default object if the first part is `nil`.)

---

I've also just noticed something else, and I think it might be the problem. Do you by any chance have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice? Because the first input from `read_string` will get overwritten by `search_string = gets.chomp`. You already set `search_string` before you passed it to the method...

---

Third thing I've noticed - your track names are being populated with newlines (`\n`). You'll need to `chomp` them as well, or follow other users' advice and look for partial matches instead of exact ones.

Comment: Where do I get the value of index from?

Comment: `index` is a method defined on `Array`. `tracks` should respond to it already.

Comment: it would actually be `tracks.index { |track| track.include?(search_string) } || -1` because they're not looking for an exact match only, that's why they call `include?`

Comment: I'll edit your answer if you don't mind

Comment: I do mind - `include?` is an Array method that looks for an exact match. That's a separate issue I've just addressed.

Comment: I think it's safe to infer from OP's use of `include?` that they are looking for a partial match, but I made my point already

Comment: It tells me that include? is an undefined method

Comment: You hould pop in with a debugger and look at the state ...

Comment: I've done that and it's only telling me what I already know, that `search_string = Sweet Caroline` and that `#<Track:0x000000000331bd18 @name="Sweet Caroline`

Comment: @spickermann is quite right, your array is full of Tracks, so you'll never find a String... and Tracks don't respond to #include? so that won't work either.